# How to access list of lists which has a map in it using Terraform 0.11?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.11

I have a few [EKS node groups](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/eks_node_group.html). I am trying to access the `autoscaling_groups` `name` of all the node groups (eg `name = eks-e214c586716a`). It's much easier in 0.12, but we are still using 0.11.

```
[
  [
    {
      "autoscaling_groups" = [
        {
          "name" = "eks-e214c586716a"
        },
      ]
      "remote_access_security_group_id" = "sg-name1"
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      "autoscaling_groups" = [
        {
          "name" = "eks-c866f3f2edb5"
        },
      ]
      "remote_access_security_group_id" = "sg-name2"
    },
  ],
]
```

This works: `aws_eks_node_group.node-group.resources.0.autoscaling_groups.0.name`

However, when I iterate through, I am unsuccessful.

```
count = "${length(var.nodegroups)}"
autoscaling_group_name    = "${element(aws_eks_node_group.node-group.resources.*.autoscaling_groups.*.name, count.index)}"
```

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but since you have a list of lists, have you tried having 2 `*`s for that? `aws_eks_node_group.node-group.resources.*.*.autoscaling_groups.*.name`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're misreading the complex data structure you have there.

You have a list of node groups which in turn contain another list that always has one element that is an object with the keys `autoscaling_groups` and `remote_access_security_group_id`. The `autoscaling_groups` key is then also another list with one element that contains an object with the key `name`.

Your attempt at doing this was to use:

```
"${element(aws_eks_node_group.node-group.resources.*.autoscaling_groups.*.name, count.index)}"
```

Which is saying to loop over the outermost list and then attempt to get the `autoscaling_groups` key from an object there when at that point it's a list with 1 element in it. You then also tried to loop over the inner most list which only has one element in it so you'd over index that if you went with:

```
"${element(aws_eks_node_group.node-group.resources.*.*.autoscaling_groups.*.name, count.index)}"
```

Because [`element`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/element.html) allows wrap around you wouldn't get an out of bound index here when trying to access the second element of a 1 element list, however Terraform doesn't let you use nested splat expressions:

```
Error: Nested splat expression not allowed

  on main.tf line 33, in resource "local_file" "asg_names":
  33:   content  = "${element(local.eks_node_group.*.*.autoscaling_groups.*.name, count.index)}"

A splat expression (*) cannot be used inside another attribute-only splat
expression.
```

So to get the autoscaling group names you want to loop over the outermost list and then take the first element of that list, get the `autoscaling_groups` key, take the first element of that list and then finally get the value from the `name` key.

Here's a basic worked example of accessing this data structure, using locals for the input and a `local_file` resource as an output to allow us to loop over it with `count`:

```
locals {
  eks_node_group = [
    [
      {
        "autoscaling_groups" = [
          {
            "name" = "eks-e214c586716a"
          },
        ]
        "remote_access_security_group_id" = "sg-name1"
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        "autoscaling_groups" = [
          {
            "name" = "eks-c866f3f2edb5"
          },
        ]
        "remote_access_security_group_id" = "sg-name2"
      },
    ],
  ]
}

resource "local_file" "asg_names" {
  count    = "${length(local.eks_node_group)}"
  filename = "${count.index}.output"
  content  = "${element(local.eks_node_group.*.0.autoscaling_groups.0.name, count.index)}"
}
```

Running the plan shows the following expected output:

```
  # local_file.asg_names[0] will be created
  + resource "local_file" "asg_names" {
      + content              = "eks-e214c586716a"
      + directory_permission = "0777"
      + file_permission      = "0777"
      + filename             = "0.output"
      + id                   = (known after apply)
    }

  # local_file.asg_names[1] will be created
  + resource "local_file" "asg_names" {
      + content              = "eks-c866f3f2edb5"
      + directory_permission = "0777"
      + file_permission      = "0777"
      + filename             = "1.output"
      + id                   = (known after apply)
    }
```

Note that unless you want the wrap around functionality of `element` as mentioned above you should really be using the more straightforward indexing syntax as `list[index]`:

```
resource "local_file" "asg_names" {
  count    = "${length(local.eks_node_group)}"
  filename = "${count.index}.output"
  content  = "${local.eks_node_group[count.index].0.autoscaling_groups.0.name}"
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer for Terraform 0.12, but I don't think this is possible -- or at least, it's very impractical -- within the Terraform 0.11 language. Terraform 0.11 only "officially" supports lists and maps of primitive types, and any support for nested data structures is more a matter of accidental implementation details than intentional language design, and so they tend to require pretty weird tricks.

Comment: Ah yeah that's a good point. I ran my test with 0.12 but using 0.11 syntax and didn't think about the different data types that changed in 0.12. The question specifies 0.11 and is tagged with it too so I'd be happy to upvote a 0.11 specific answer and potentially delete my answer in favour of it.